# Please I'm a newbie to using pug with reactjs, so what should I do when I face this bug, ERROR in utils.getReturnPropertyAndNode is not a function?

Tags: reactjs, pug

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

function App(props) {
  return pug`
  div.App
    header.App-header
      img(src=logo className="App-logo" alt="logo")
      p
        | Edit 
        code src/App.js
        |  and save to reload.
      a(
        className="App-link"
        href="https://reactjs.org"
        target="_blank"
        rel="noopener noreferrer"
      ) Learn React
  `;
}

export default App;
```

ERROR in utils.getReturnPropertyAndNode is not a function, it seems the error occured when linting like is showing me on my VS Code and Rule: "react-pug/prop-types"

Answer (score 0):

You need commas between you element values

```
img(src=logo className="App-logo" alt="logo")
```

should be

```
img(src=logo, className="App-logo", alt="logo")
```

and

```
 a(
    className="App-link"
    href="https://reactjs.org"
    target="_blank"
    rel="noopener noreferrer"
  ) Learn React
```

should be

```
a(className="App-link", href="https://reactjs.org", target="_blank", rel="noopener noreferrer")
```

Comment: I have added the commas, but the bug is still there @Pixelomo